# volley NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

i am using volley.jar 
there's no error on compile time but there's runtime exception.

and i add volley.jar and add build path. what is problem?

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:150)
>       at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:199)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1682)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1447)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1894)
>       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1805)
>       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
>       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
>       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1637)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2144)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1682)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1536)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1445)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14898)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2014)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1771)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1013)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5746)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<Games> rowItems;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Games> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    NetworkImageView profile_pic;
    TextView member_name;
    TextView status;
    TextView contactType;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.profile_pic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);

        Games row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        ImageLoader il = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        holder.profile_pic.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL ,il);


        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getChampionId());
        holder.status.setText(row_pos.getGameMode());
        holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getStats().getItem0());
        Log.d("aaa", "position : " + position );
        Log.d("aaa", "row_pos.getChampionId()" + row_pos.getChampionId());
        Log.d("aaa", "row_pos.getGameMode()" + row_pos.getGameMode());
        Log.d("aaa", "row_pos.getStats().getItem0()" + row_pos.getStats().getItem0());

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Games row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        ImageLoader il = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        holder.profile_pic.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL,il);

        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getChampionId());
        holder.status.setText(row_pos.getGameMode());
        holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getStats().getItem0());
        Log.d("aaa", "position : " + position );
        Log.d("aaa", "row_pos.getChampionId()" + row_pos.getChampionId());
        Log.d("aaa", "row_pos.getGameMode()" + row_pos.getGameMode());
        Log.d("aaa", "row_pos.getStats().getItem0()" + row_pos.getStats().getItem0());

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

## list_item.xml

LinearLayout

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:contentDescription="desc"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/member_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_pic"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="txt"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/member_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/member_name"
    android:text="txt"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/member_name"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/member_name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="txt" />
```

Comment: make sure you are not passing empty parameters to url

Comment: make sure your values for `IMAGE_URL` are correct

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problems.
There's some errors in my volleysingleton class getImageLoader method this code run well.